# Execute compiled executable C file without ./

Tags: c

I have compiled using the command:

```
$gcc -o xyz xyz.c
```

Is there a way to execute this in C other than using:

```
$./xyz <arg list>
```

I want to execute it without ' **./** ' as:

```
$xyz <arg list>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: put `.` in the path if you don't fear the security issues (nothing to do with C)

Comment: thank you. @Jean-FrançoisFabre